# Error while importing scala.collection.breakOut

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import

I am getting this error in IntelliJ:

> object breakOut is not a member of package collection
> import scala.collection.{breakOut, mutable}

Can you suggest me which package I should add or if the can share the code for breakOut class maybe defining it will work ?

Comment: I am using scala -2.11  as dependency

Comment: This is likely an issue with IntelliJ or your build definition, the method do exist for Scala 2.11 in this package. Maybe whare with us how your build is defined: sbt, Maven? Is the Scala SDK correctly setup in IntelliJ?

Comment: Ya I used scala sdk 2.13 that's why I was getting this error , later I changed it to 2.11 too and it got fixed . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

breakOut was in the Scala standard library until Scala 2.13. You shouldn't need to depend on any additional libraries. In Scala 2.13 and later, you should remove that parameter and explicitly convert to the required type, e. g. using `toList`, `toMap`, `toSet` or whatever it is that's required.